# Execute wp-cli command on all sites on server

Tags: wp-cli

Im pretty sure someone knows the answer, i'm trying to find a way to execute wp cli commands to all sites on my server.

So my directory structure is /srv/users/serververpilot/apps/*/public

The asterisk is where all the sites are located in, each site has a different public directory.

So I know I can run something like:

```
wp core update --path='/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myfirstsite/public/'
wp core update --path='/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mysecondsite/public/'
wp core update --path='/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/mythirdsite/public/'
```

However what i'm looking for is how can I mass run Wordpress updates via wp cli to all sites under /srv/users/serververpilot/apps/*/public

Anyone has any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `find` with a *directory* type and zero *maxdepth*:

```
$ find /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/*/public/ \
-type d \
-maxdepth 0 \
-exec /usr/local/bin/wp core update --path={} \;
```

or in a single line:

```
$ find /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/*/public/ -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec /usr/local/bin/wp core update --path={} \;
```